# How to add colors in theme in vue3 and vuetify3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am updating an old vue2 app to vue3, I would like to make 3 global colors, red, green and gray. I am currently doing the following in `vuetify.js`

```
// Styles
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'
// Vuetify
import { createVuetify, ThemeDefinition } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify(
  {
    theme: {
      dark: false, // or true if you want a dark theme
      themes: {
        light: {
          primary: '#3f51b5', // your primary color
          secondary: '#b0bec5', // your secondary color
          accent: '#8c9eff', // your accent color
        },
      }
    }
}
)
```

However I would actually like to make global env variables so I can easily do it like

`<v-toolbar primary>`

Comment: `<v-toolbar primary>` implies a prop named `primary` that sets... text? background? something? to be the primary color.  but props are written into the API, and you can't just create custom props for another library's components.  it's too much wishful magical thinking.  just use class names like the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/) suggests, e.g. `class="bg-primary"`.

Comment: So how would you suggest I apply colors?

Comment: "apply colors" is a bit vague.  components are made up a many sub-components, elements, texts, etc..  how should "primary" color be applied to v-toolbar?  you've not explained.  If it's general background color or text color, classnames like I just mentioned will work, `bg-primary` or `text-primary`.  For more specific targeting, you can reference theme colors directly in your component CSS with `var()`.  Review the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#custom-theme-colors) as it explains everything you need.

Comment: Yes bg primary text primary that's what I want to target where should I put that

Comment: Btw: To set color like <v-toolbar primary/> doesn't work at all. You need to use <v-toolbar color="primary"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify, ThemeDefinition } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify({
  theme: {
    dark: false,
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: '#3f51b5',
        secondary: '#b0bec5',
        accent: '#8c9eff',
        'red': '#FF0000',
        'green': '#00FF00',
        'gray': '#333333'
      },
    }
  }
})
```

And in your VToolbar:

```
<v-toolbar color="green" />
```

---

Btw: If you want to use green and red for validation you can use (and edit) the Vuetify default colors `success` and `error`.